# FreeTextBox HTML uneditable

Tags: asp.net, repeater, freetextbox

For using FreeTextBox in a repeator, there is an issue where when clicking on from Design to the HTML option, it is just a full blue background and the HTML is uneditable.  Note it seems to work good in a regular approach, but in clicking on HTML in a repeator it does not show.

Comment: at least edit the relevant problem code in post

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was creating a sample and found it was caused by an extra line of CSS code that was making the FreeTextbox not work for editing HTML.